# Separating items in an array with a new line

Tags: arrays, string

I have an array **:**

```
const array = ["String1", "String2", "String3"]
```

I'm trying to separate into something like this **:**

```
String1
String2
String3
```

I want it to be separated just like that, but like in one message.

Do you have any idea on how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Are you trying to print those strings? Which programming language are you using? What code have you tried thus far?

Comment: I'm using Javascript, and I'm coding a discord bot that will send this message,  and I've tried to do const.join(" ") and that gave me partially want I wanted (String1 String2 String3) , but now I want the strings to be seperated on a new line to make the message easier to read.

Comment: maybe join with something else, like a new line character?

Comment: is that a thing

Answer (score 1):

Solved by pm100

```
    const array = ["String1", "String2", "String3"]
    
    console.log(array.join('\n'))
```

'\n' separates the strings on a new line.

Comment: This is life saver answer. Excellent